# Organising Rails SASS files in folders

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass

I have a stock rails 3.1 application, and have been struggling with organising my sass files in folders.

- If I create a manifest file that imports foo.css.scss, and I put
  foo.css.scss in a sub folder, the file is not imported.
- If I put both the manifest and foo.css.scss in the subfolder, then
  foo.css.scss is found, however images referenced in the css are not
  found, unless I move back a directory.

as:

```
body {background-image:url('paper.gif');} // Not found.
body {background-image:url('../paper.gif');} // found.
```

What is the correct way to use subfolders with SASS and Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
body {background-image:image-url('paper.gif');}
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html chapter 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I put all my images in the `assets/images` folder instead of subfoldering them in a css/stylesheets directory hidden from other image files.

I'd assume your bullet point #2 with moving images to the folder i mentioned should work regardless of what sledgehammer you are using to complicate simple CSS.

Comment: I also put all my images are in the assets/images folder, and that is where they reside in the example given above.